# How to parse ObjectId in a pydantic model?

Tags: python, mongodb, parsing, objectid, pydantic

I am trying to parse MongoDB records to a pydantic model but failing to do so for `ObjectId`

From what I understood, I need to setup validator for ObjectId and did try to both extend ObjectId class and add the `validator` decorator to my class using ObjectId. which I did as follows.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from bson.objectid import ObjectId


class ObjectId(ObjectId):
    pass
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate
    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        if not isinstance(v, ObjectId):
            raise TypeError('ObjectId required')
        return str(v)


class User(BaseModel):
    who: ObjectId


class User1(BaseModel):
    who: ObjectId
    @validator('who')
    def validate(cls, v):
        if not isinstance(v, ObjectId):
            raise TypeError('ObjectId required')
        return str(v)

data = {"who":ObjectId('123456781234567812345678')}
```

Unfortunately, both "solution"  are failing as follows:

```py
>>> test = User(**data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 274, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for User
id
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

```py
>>> test = User1(**data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 274, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for User1
who
  ObjectId required (type=type_error)
```

There is definitely something that I am missing here.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## Pydantic 1

You first test case works fine. The problem is with how you overwrite `ObjectId`.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from bson.objectid import ObjectId as BsonObjectId


class PydanticObjectId(BsonObjectId):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        if not isinstance(v, BsonObjectId):
            raise TypeError('ObjectId required')
        return str(v)


class User(BaseModel):
    who: PydanticObjectId


print(User(who=BsonObjectId('123456781234567812345678')))
```

prints

```
who='123456781234567812345678'
```

Only pydantic should use pydantic type. Mongo will provide you with bsons ObjectId. So instantiate your data with real ObjectId.
So `data = {"who":ObjectId('123456781234567812345678')}` is wrong, as it uses your child ObjectId class.

## Pydantic 2

Use AfterValidator https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/

```py
from typing_extensions import Annotated
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.functional_validators import AfterValidator
from bson import ObjectId as _ObjectId


def check_object_id(value: str) -> str:
    if not _ObjectId.is_valid(value):
        raise ValueError('Invalid ObjectId')
    return value


ObjectId = Annotated[str, AfterValidator(check_object_id)]


class Example(BaseModel):
    id: ObjectId


print(Example(id='5f9b3b3b9d9f3d0001a3b3b3'))
print(Example(id='1'))
```

Comment: new solution for `Pydantic2` ?

Comment: @AliRn https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/

I did this
```
from typing_extensions import Annotated
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.functional_validators import AfterValidator
from bson import ObjectId as _ObjectId


def check_object_id(value: str) -> str:
    if not _ObjectId.is_valid(value):
        raise ValueError('Invalid ObjectId')
    return value


ObjectId = Annotated[str, AfterValidator(check_object_id)]


class Example(BaseModel):
    id: ObjectId


print(Example(id='5f9b3b3b9d9f3d0001a3b3b3'))
print(Example(id='1'))
```

Comment: Why are all of these validators seemingly returning `str` objects instead of `ObjectId` instances? Firstly `return str(v)`, then `def check_object_id(value: str) -> str:`...

Answer (score 10):

Just another way to do this is with pydantic that i found useful from another source is:

Define a file called PyObjectId.py in a models folder.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field as PydanticField
from bson import ObjectId

class PyObjectId(ObjectId):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate
    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        if not ObjectId.is_valid(v):
            raise ValueError("Invalid objectid")
        return ObjectId(v)
    @classmethod
    def __modify_schema__(cls, field_schema):
        field_schema.update(type="string")
```

Then you can use this in any of your object files like this
users.py

```
from models.PyObjectId import PyObjectId
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field as PydanticField
from bson import ObjectId
class Users(BaseModel):
    id: PyObjectId = PydanticField(default_factory=PyObjectId, alias="_id")
    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True #required for the _id 
        json_encoders = {ObjectId: str}
```

Answer (score 7):

Getting Started with MongoDB and FastAPI

[Mongo Developers](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/quickstart/python-quickstart-fastapi/)

This code help you to use json encoder

```
from bson import ObjectId
from pydantic import BaseModel


class ObjId(ObjectId):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v: str):
        try:
            return cls(v)
        except InvalidId:
            raise ValueError("Not a valid ObjectId")


class Foo(BaseModel):
    object_id_field: ObjId = None

    class Config:
        json_encoders = {
            ObjId: lambda v: str(v),
        }



obj = Foo(object_id_field="60cd778664dc9f75f4aadec8")
print(obj.dict())
# {'object_id_field': ObjectId('60cd778664dc9f75f4aadec8')}
print(obj.json())
# {'object_id_field': '60cd778664dc9f75f4aadec8'}
```

### UPDATE:

You can use this Field type in your pydantic model:

```
from bson import ObjectId as BaseObjectId

class ObjectId(str):
"""Creating a ObjectId class for pydantic models."""

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, value):
        """Validate given str value to check if good for being ObjectId."""
        try:
            return BaseObjectId(str(value))
        except InvalidId as e:
            raise ValueError("Not a valid ObjectId") from e

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking the answers and other articles, I Use the following object and use `ENCODERS_BY_TYPE` from `pydantic.json` to make the encoding global from `str` to `ObjectId` and vice versa.

```py
import bson
import bson.errors 
from pydantic.json import ENCODERS_BY_TYPE


class ObjectId(bson.ObjectId):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        raise_error = False

        try:
            if isinstance(v, str):
                v = bson.ObjectId(v)

            if (
                not isinstance(v, (bson.ObjectId, cls))
                or not bson.ObjectId.is_valid(v)
            ):
                raise_error = True
        except bson.errors.InvalidId:
            raise_error = True

        if raise_error:
            raise ValueError("Invalid ObjectId")

        return v

    @classmethod
    def __modify_schema__(cls, field_schema):
        field_schema.update(type="string")


if ObjectId not in ENCODERS_BY_TYPE:
    ENCODERS_BY_TYPE[ObjectId] = str
    ENCODERS_BY_TYPE[bson.ObjectId] = str
```

Answer (score 1):

After many experimentations I landed on this solution:

## Tested with python 3.11

```py
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


@classmethod
def __get_validators__(cls):
    yield injected_validator


def injected_validator(v):
    if not isinstance(v, ObjectId):
        raise TypeError('ObjectId required')

    return v


# This does the trick. It forces ObjectId to have a validator 
ObjectId.__get_validators__ = __get_validators__


def parse_object_id(v):
    if isinstance(v, str) and ObjectId.is_valid(v):
        return ObjectId(v)    

    if isinstance(v, ObjectId):
        return v

    raise TypeError(f"Invalid ObjectId: {v}")


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    id: ObjectId | None

    @validator("id", pre=True)
    def ensure_id_is_object_id(cls, v):
        return None if v is None else parse_object_id(v)


def ensure_oid(v):
    assert type(v.id) == ObjectId


assert MyModel().id is None

ensure_oid(MyModel(id=ObjectId()))
ensure_oid(MyModel(id=ObjectId("642796132887d08ca3a7a986")))

# Intellisense warn (but works): Expected type 'ObjectId | None', got 'str' instead
ensure_oid(MyModel(id="642796430b2fb0ed6292d1d2"))

ensure_oid(MyModel.parse_obj({"id": ObjectId()}))
ensure_oid(MyModel.parse_obj({"id": "642796893cd44d9ff690a455"}))
ensure_oid(MyModel.parse_obj({"id": ObjectId("642796abb14eb1e6a9183ae5")}))
ensure_oid(MyModel.parse_raw('{"id": "642796924f9a0adbea020d60"}'))
```

Unfortunately I couldn't get this working with `_id` field name. If you find the sollution, please share it with me!

A workaround to this would be to create a property `_id` like this:

```py
@property
def _id(self) -> ObjectId | None:
    return self.id
```

Answer (score 1):

I will share my solution for **pydantic 2**.

For my use case, I needed that when the data enters the model as an ObjectId, I parse it to str. when it comes in as str I parse it to ObjectId

```
from typing_extensions import Annotated

from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict
from pydantic.functional_validators import AfterValidator

from bson.objectid import ObjectId


def object_id_validate(v: ObjectId | str) -> ObjectId | str:
    assert ObjectId.is_valid(v), f'{v} is not a valid ObjectId'
    if isinstance(v, str):
        return ObjectId(v)
    return str(v)


PyObjectId = Annotated[ObjectId | str, AfterValidator(object_id_validate)]


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(arbitrary_types_allowed=True)
    user_id: PyObjectId


print(MyModel(user_id=str(ObjectId()))) # user_id=ObjectId('653087c8c8640ef5700a1bb5')
print(MyModel(user_id=ObjectId())) # user_id='653087c8c8640ef5700a1bb6'
```

Answer (score 0):

Tom Wojcik's solution slightly modified worked for me:

```
class PydanticObjectId(BsonObjectId):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        if not isinstance(v, BsonObjectId):
            raise TypeError('ObjectId required')
        return str(v)
    
class Bird(BaseModel):
    id: PydanticObjectId = Field(..., alias="_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom type I use *(FastAPI: 0.109.0, Pydantic: 2.5.3)*:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, ConfigDict

def validate_object_id(v: Any) -> ObjectId:
    if isinstance(v, ObjectId):
        return v
    if ObjectId.is_valid(v):
        return ObjectId(v)
    raise ValueError("Invalid ObjectId")

ObjectIdType = Annotated[
    str | ObjectId,
    PlainSerializer(lambda x: str(x), return_type=str, when_used="json"),
    AfterValidator(validate_object_id),
    WithJsonSchema({"type": "string"}, mode="serialization"),
]
```

Please pay attention to **when_used="json"** it allows to use default **.model_dump** method and have ObjectId there by default. In json mode ObjectId will be converted to string, so it will work fine for FastApi.

```
class BaseMongoModel(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(populate_by_alias=True, populate_by_name=True, arbitrary_types_allowed=True,
                              validate_assignment=True)

    id: ObjectIdType | None = Field(None, alias="_id")
```