# How to use MongoObjectId in pydanic models

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have created a simple REST API using Python, FastAPI and Pydantic.

It is working OK. But the model file create `_id` with `uuid` instead of Mongo `ObjectId`.

```
id: uuid.UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid.uuid4, alias="_id")
```

How can I use Mongo ObjectId?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse ObjectId in a pydantic model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503461/how-to-parse-objectid-in-a-pydantic-model)